# Не работает clearIntreval в функции, но при этом работает на кнопку

Tags: javascript, clearinterval

Почему не срабатывает clearInterval в функции moveTo
при этом все работает на кнопку паузы.

```
var timerid = 0,
    counterid = 0;

function playPages() {
    var sec = 3;
    timerid = setInterval(counterid = moveTo(sec), sec * 1000);
}

function moveTo(sec) {
    clearInterval(counterid)
    document.getElementById('backcounter').innerText = sec;
    return setInterval(changeBackcounter, 1000);
}

function changeBackcounter() {
    var temp = document.getElementById('backcounter').innerText;
    document.getElementById('backcounter').innerText = --temp;
}

function pausePages() {
    clearInterval(counterid);
}

document.getElementById('play').addEventListener("click", playPages);
document.getElementById('pause').addEventListener("click", pausePages);
```

Comment: Так вы интервалу задаете идентификатор `timerid` а остановить пытаетесь `counterid`

Comment: Я так понял два и больше setinterval задать одновременно не возможно, а так да я хочу остановить counterid что бы счетчик начался с начала, а первый интервал должен продолжать работать

Comment: одновременно задать можно. каждый вызов setInterval, возвращает id запущенного таймера. Что происходит  в коде метода  moveTo/playPages - непонятно.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно надо изменить функцию PlayPages

```
function playPages() {
    var sec = 3;
    timerid = setInterval(function(){
        counterid = moveTo(sec)
    }, sec * 1000);
}
```

Comment: так тоже пробовал, не помогает

Answer (score 0):

Коллеги всем спасибо кто пытался помочь, все правильно за исключением вот этого

```
timerid = setInterval(counterid = moveTo(sec), sec * 1000);
```

второй аргумент должен быть переменной или числом, выражение он не принимал

Comment: где в этой строке _второй_ аргумент?

Comment: второй аргумент sec * 1000

Comment: _sec * 1000_ - вполне себе возвращает число. Следовательно проблема явно не в этом.

Comment: что вообще должна была делать эта строка? учитывая, что _moveTo_ возвращает число, а не функцию. Какая ошибка была в консоли браузера?